# Passing uri between compose screens causes: SecurityException: Permission Denial

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I receive a uri in screen "A" by:

```
val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { activityResult ->
        if(activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val uri = activityResult.data?.data!!
            context.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            viewModel.onUriReceived(uri)
        }
    }
LaunchedEffect(launcher) {
     val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI).apply {
         addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
         type = "video/*"
         addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
         addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
     }
     coroutineScope.launch {
         launcher.launch(intent)
     }
  }
```

I can open the uri in screen "A" but if I pass the uri to screen "B" I receive:

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/video:38 from pid=6074, uid=10146 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2425)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:153)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:780)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:2027)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1842)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1518)
```

---

Github repo to reproduce the error: https://github.com/geckogecko/PermissionDenialPlayground
Happened with: Pixel 2 API 28, Pixel 4a API 31, Pixel 5 API 31 emulators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the content of `it.getString("imageUri")`, you'll see the following:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:20
```

And if you try to encode/decode your media uri with the following code:

```kotlin
val encoded = Uri.encode(uri.toString())
val decoded = Uri.decode(encoded)
val decoded2 = Uri.decode(decoded)
println("original: $uri")
println(" encoded: $encoded")
println(" decoded: $decoded")
println("decodedSecond: $decodedSecond")
```

You should see this:

```
original: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A20
 encoded: content%3A%2F%2Fcom.android.providers.media.documents%2Fdocument%2Fimage%253A20
 decoded: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A20
decoded2: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:20
```

Android navigation decodes the arguments on its own, and it looks like it does it multiple times, since you see that the navigation argument equals the result `decoded2` rather than `decoded`.

The reason is that original uri contains encoding symbol `'%'`, so `'%3A'` becomes `':'` after the second decoding phase.

A possible solution is to add your own additional "encoding" for this symbol. I chose `'|'` because I expect it will not be represented in any uri that the android system will give you, but you can come up with another character if you have problems.

```kotlin
val encoded = Uri.encode(uri.toString().replace('%','|'))
navController.navigate("screenB?imageUri=$encoded")
```

Decode:

```kotlin
val uri = it.arguments?.let {
    it.getString("imageUri")
        ?.replace('|','%')
        ?.let(Uri::parse)
}
```

---

Another option is not to encode it, but to store it in some container inside a repository, shared between routes in some way - it may be singleton or Hilt DI, etc. So you pass the container id as an argument, in general this is the recommended approach for Compose Navigation.